# Solving Differential Equation with Complex Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation that involves complex numbers.

How do I solve this differential equation?

$$\dot{z}=iz+\frac{1-2i}{2}\sin (t)$$

If you can use variation of parameters, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried to get a solution but my solution is different from the result in MATLAB.

In MATLAB, I get the following solution:

$$z=C_1e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+\sin t\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)$$

By using the variation of parameters, I am getting the following equation

$$z=C_1e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+e^{-ix}\left(\frac{i}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\right)$$

I am not sure where the extra sin(t) is coming from.

Comment: I would multiply both sides by exp^(-At) and then integrate. Then divide both sides be exp(-At)

Answer (score 1):

We first solve the homogeneous problem $$\dot z - iz = 0.$$
The solution to this is given by $z = Ce^{it}$ for some arbitrary constant $C$.

As you asked for a solution by variation of parameters, we now form the particular integral by trying \begin{align*}
z_p &= f(x) e^{it} \\
\implies \dot z_p &= f'(x) e^{it} + i f(x) e^{it},
\end{align*}
where $f(x)$ is a function to be found.
Substituting into the original differential equation,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) e^{it} + if(x) e^{it} &= if(X) e^{it} + \frac{1-2i}{2} \sin t \\
f'(x) &= \frac{1-2i}{2} e^{-it} \sin t.
\end{align*}
Integrating, $$f(x) = \left(\frac 14 + \frac i8\right)\left(-2t + ie^{-2it}\right).$$
Thus the general solution is $$z = Ce^{it} + \left(\frac 14 + \frac i8\right)\left(-2te^{it} + ie^{-it}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution
$$z=C_1e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+e^{-ix}\left(\frac{i}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\right)$$
(which btw you should have detailed in your post)
is *not* "different from the result in MATLAB"
$$\begin{align}z&=C_2e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+\sin t\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)\\
&=C_2e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)\\
&=\left(C_2+\frac1{4i}\right)e^{ix}-te^{ix}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}\right)+e^{-ix}\left(\frac{i}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\right).
\end{align}$$